# "With" / "together" meaning of the に particle

Tags: grammar, particle-に

While studying the basic functions of particles, I came across the following sentence:

パン***に***コーヒーか紅茶を飲みます
(I have coffee or tea **with** / **together with** bread)

I don't know if this is the correct translation of that Japanese phrase, but it is nevertheless a usage of the particle に that I had not seen before and that I do not seem to find much about online.

What would the literal translation of that phrase be in English?
What is the function of the particle in this case?

I have heard that this type of expression is used while ordering something in a restaurant or while buying things, as well as when describing what someone is wearing (as in "スーツにスニーカーを履く).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

に can mean *addition* (添加 [#8 here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%AB/#je-56984)).

It can be considered as *with*, but it adds a nuance of *in addition to, on top of*. Other than those in questions,

- 小麦粉に卵を混ぜる throw egg to flour and stir
- ソーセージにビールが最高 Beer (in addition) to sausages is the best

---

FYI some other に/と questions.

- [Confusion between ~に似てる　~と似てる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/77924/45489)
- [Does 関係 use particle に or と?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46617/45489)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. There are other definitions of this に such as

- to (公園に行きます/I’m going to the park)
- for (ケ-キ作るために牛乳を使う/I will use the milk for the cake)
- as (私にはカッコいいと思う/to[as] me, I think it’s cool)

There are many others, too. You can take a look at them [here](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%AB). In this case, the に is being used as “with” because of it being noun (パン) + noun/phrase of it being an item (コ-ヒ-か紅茶) + indication of the object (を) + verb having to do with the two nouns (飲みます).

Edit: I would translate it as “On top of bread, I’ll have coffee or tea.” The reason being the physical actions taken for *eating* bread is different from *drinking* coffee or tea.

Comment: In your second example sentence, did you mean to provide a sentence with に?

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake xD